# Any free C# ssh server libraries or an alternative secure remote console solution?

Tags: c#, security, ssh

I have an application that provides real time log messages for users. Currently the application works by having the server listen on a straight forward TCP socket and the users can use a telnet client to connect. Once connected they get asked for their username, password and can then set a filter for the realtime events they want sent to them.

While no sensitive information is sent over the telnet session the application is getting to a stage where it's increased use warrants tightening up on security.

Ideally the console should be universally accessible from a shell on Windows, Linux and Macs. The only options that came to mind for that are telnet and ssh. As far as I know there's no way to increase security using a standard telnet client so that leaves ssh. Has anyone got any experience with an C# SSH server library or know of a different solution I could use? Is there some clever trick where a WCF endpoint can process ssh clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mostly working C# SSH server over at CodePlex that I wrote: [NSsh](http://nssh.codeplex.com/)

It currently supports password based authentication. I was looking at extending it to support certificate based authentication but it is a bit tricky under Windows.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a whirl. Password authentication is all I need.

Comment: @sipwiz Let me know if you run into and problems, I'm always happy to help.

Comment: @Luke: NSsh looks like it could be prefect for me. I've started playing and have created the project's first issue on codeplex :).